# Need to understand the difference in behavior for the below code interms of memory leak

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I have gone through objective-C literals & class methods, but I am not clear from Memory point of View. I am confused to use which version of the code. I have two piece of code & I would like to understand the difference between them from Memory Leak point of View.

Assuming that "returnArray" is Array to be returned

**Version 1**

```
if([tempArray count] > 0) {
    for(NSDictionary *dict in tempArray) {

        NSDictionary *tempDict = [
                                  [NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [dict objectForKey:@"verifiedEmail"],@"verifiedEmail",
                                  [dict objectForKey:@"identifier"], @"identifier",
                                  nil
                                  ];

        [returnArray addObject:tempDict];
    }
}
```

**Version2**

```
if([tempArray count] > 0) {
    for(NSDictionary *dict in tempArray) {
        NSDictionary *tempDict = @{
                                 @"verifiedEmail" : [dict objectForKey:@"verifiedEmail"],
                                 @"identifier" : [dict objectForKey:@"identifier"],
                                 };
        [returnArray addObject:tempDict];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are not sure about memory management use arc

Comment: Couple notes: if one of the dictionaries is missing the `verifiedEmail` value, version 1 will create an empty tempDict, and version 2 will crash. And `[dict objectForKey:@"identifier"]` can now be written as `dict[@"identifier"]`.

Comment: Sorry not clear that its a memory management query But on version 1 it is cleared that you are allocating a dictionary and not releasing that.So there is leak(no need to check).You should put release then ask the difference.I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that you are NOT using ARC:

- Version 1, the rule states that object with alloc, new or copy give object a retain count of 1. So you are creating tempdict without releasing it in the future, that's a leak
- Version 2, since you are not using none of the words above you are creating an autoreleased object, that goes into the autorelease pool, this object in the future if none will take its ownership will be released. In that particular case the array will take the ownership.

Comment: You answer talks about non-arc environment. What if, If I am using ARC & have to choose one out of the two version ..?

Comment: If you are not using ARC, for Objective-c object you don't have to worry about memory management. But is important to understand it, because with ARC the compiler use the same rules. Choose the second 'cause is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1 is creating a dictionary everytime and version two is giving out an autoreleased version of dictionary.
Version 2 is equivalent to `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys]` method.

Comment: That is not entirely correct, version 2 is equivalent to `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:`. But this makes no difference with respect to memory management.

Answer (score 0):

In manual memory management when you `alloc` an object such as `[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:` you are getting a **retained object**. means you are responsible to release that object. Where as   `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys]`  giving you a **autoreleased object**. Your second version of code is modern objective c style creating dictionary same as `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys]`(in particular replacement for *+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:]*) . In memory concern second one is autoreleased. If you are not sure about memory management use ARC

Answer (score 0):

You will leak memory using Version 1. You're allocating an NSDictionary but then overwriting its pointer (the local tempDict) so have no way to release it. Version 2 will not leak memory since the creation of the NSDictionary object creates an auto-released object. (All of this assumes you are using Manual Retain/Release, rather than ARC.)